# Weight conversion C++

Tags: c++

Hey so I am trying a question that asks this, bare in mind I am just learning but I am not sure how to do it, so any help would be appreciated.

Q. Write a program which will convert a weight in KG to pounds and ounces or vice versa depending on the user input. Use the following simple menu:
WEIGHT CONVERSION OPTIONS:
  A) KG TO POUNDS AND OUNCES.
  B) POUNDS AND OUNCES TO KG.
ENTER OPTION A OR B.

so far I have the following but thats all I could do before I got stuck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
float kg, ounces;
int pounds;
char option;

    cout << "WEIGHT CONVERSION OPTIONS \n" << "     " << "A) KG to pounds: \n" << "     " << "B) Pounds to KG: \n " <<"Enter option A or B: \n";
    cin.get(option);

if(option == A)
    kg = option*2.2046;
    cout << kg;
else if(option == B)
    pounds = option/2.2046;
    cout << pounds;


system("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: Stuck how? Where is the question? You're also missing braces around your if statements.

Comment: Just wondering what `A*2.2046` is supposed to equal. You need to get the actual input, not just the option.

Comment: @chris that is the conversion rate from pounds to KG that I was given

Comment: @Rapptz I can't get the IF statments to work it says A is not a viable option and the question is just above the code

Comment: Put (single) quotes around `A` and `B`. Also, you're not letting the user input the actual numbers, therefore rendering the program useless :P

Comment: @TAM What is the *exact* error message? Please copy and paste it here as summarizing often loses critical information we need to help you.

Comment: @TAM, I know, but you're multiplying one character that the user enters  by a number.

Comment: @David You mean *single* quotes, correct?

Comment: @David thanks for that I know have the single quotes

Comment: @Code-Guru Correct, should've specified that. I haven't been involved in C++ since forever :)

Comment: @chris Oh yeah I need to add a cout and cin statement into each IF to get user input number Doh!

Comment: @Code-Guru My else statement has a Red line under it and says Error: expected a statement.

Comment: @TAM, The thing that can really get you is that `'A' * 2.2046` will, in most cases, give a result of 143.299, because `'A'` gets promoted to a float (because `kg` is one) with the value 65 (which is the ASCII for 'A' and why I said in most cases). That would be a bit annoying to have to debug.

Comment: grams are mass and pounds are weight, and any ass can keep them straight.

Comment: @emsr, True, but this is America's measurements system we're talking about. I guess the question assumes we're talking about objects at the perfect height level on Earth.

Comment: @TAM You get that error message because you have missed the curly braces around the statements inside the `if` and `else` clauses in your code. Double-check the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues:

- You forgot to put single quotes around the option.
- You didn't ask for the user to input anything regarding their own weight.
- You're using `system("PAUSE")` to pause the screen, which isn't a good way of doing it.
- You have an unused variable, `ounces`.

> [possible solution](http://ideone.com/AqrnZO)

Comment: I have resolved points one and two now but what Is a better way of doing number 3? that is the only method I have learnt at this moment

Comment: @TAM, `std::cin.get();`, with an additional preceding `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` before it if you're using `cin >>` instead of `getline`. Alternatively, just run the program from the command line :)

Comment: Yeah what chris said. For numeric_limits you have to include `<limits>` or you could just use a value you feel comfortable with like `cin.ignore(100,'\n')` but that isn't as good.

Comment: The difference is that the `numeric_limits` approach gets the maximum number of characters it could possibly discard, whereas something like 100 is an arbitrary number, so if they enter more than 100 extra characters, it won't get rid of all of them.

Comment: @Rapptz, I like your possible solution addition, but you used `int` instead of `double` :)

Comment: @chris you saw nothing. *fixes*

Comment: @chris thank you, your input has been very useful turns out all I was missing after fixing the points above was braces

Comment: `system("pause")` wouldn't normally go into a final program, but it's handy to keep the Visual Studio window from disappearing immediately when the program finishes when running in debug mode (as opposed to "run without debugging").  Do you have an alternate, better suggestion?

Comment: @TAM, I'm glad you appreciate it. The whole pause replacement thing makes a bit more sense after you settle into the language a bit more, so just remind yourself to find out exactly why it works in the future :)

Comment: @phonetagger, Put a breakpoint in.